# IDE autocompletion for javascript AMD loading style

Tags: javascript, ide, amd

Does anyone know of an IDE that can autocomplete javascript AMD style :

```
// my dojoConfig defined aliases to the packages I use (dojo, dmidz)
// so in dmidz/my-module.js
define(['dojo/dom-construct'], function(cons){// requiring some dojo module
   cons.// <- oh it is nicely displaying list of dom-construct module methods
});
```

Please don't just give the best, cool IDE you like. I tried Komodo and Webstorm, I just couldn't make them work, or maybe I had not configured them correctly...but none give the possibility to set the same alias as in dojoConfig (too difficult?).
For example in Webstorm, there is a library concept, I added dojo and my package, but no way, of course, how it could without knowing the alias paths. There is also a Path Variables concept, no way to understand how it works, the documentation is so poor!

Thank for any help.

Comment: You can ask directly to WebStorm support via its bugtracker http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB?p=375&f=false. The support there is awesome! (I don't work for them ;) )

Comment: this should be the most important question for any amd javascript developer. even for those who write in non-amd modules they need to know their context/scope's content from the page loading the js files.

Answer (score 15):

You might be looking for TernJS. [It declares support of RequireJS via a plugin](http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html#plugin_requirejs)

It is the best tool I know for the job. Tern is rather RAM-hungry, though (compared to a pure text editor).
Integration with Sublime Text is seamless, and with other Sublime plugins you can bring it quite close to a definition of IDE.

Below is an excerpt from TernJS documentation:

> Tern is a stand-alone code-analysis engine for JavaScript. It is
>   intended to be used with a code editor plugin to enhance the editor's
>   support for intelligent JavaScript editing. Features provided are:
>
> - Autocompletion on variables and properties
> - Function argument hints
> - Querying the type of an expression
> - Finding the definition of something
> - Automatic refactoring
>
> Tern is open-source (MIT license), written in JavaScript, and capable
>   of running both on node.js and in the browser. Editor plugins
>
> There is currently Tern support for the following editors:
>
> - Emacs
> - Vim
> - Sublime Text
> - Brackets (built in to the base editor)

Comment: thank you for the trail, but the doc around requireJS is talking about 2 globals define and requirejs which the second is not the one specified by requireJS and used everywhere : it is 'require', maybe the doc is outdated ? Then it recognize only 2 options baseURL and paths, not packages, well I can try to use only paths to see if it can catch my structure...and it is the most configurable I have seen so far. I tried Brackets, node scripted also, but none has requireConfig...did you tried Cloud9 ? not been able to install it and test it quickly. One more prob : some uses exports, dojo not...

Comment: My feeling is that the doc was last updated long ago. The plugin's [source code](https://github.com/marijnh/tern/blob/master/plugin/requirejs.js) evidently supports `require`.

Answer (score 1):

Well I am using PHPStorm 8.1 (Webstorm should be ok also) now and...
**AMD autocompletion works well !**
I just declare my js packages as javascript libraries :

Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries > Add...

add and point to each of your packages'folder and enjoy :) Have to mention JetBrains IDE rocks, give it a try, sure you will adopt it since - at least - it resolves AMD style...

Answer (score 0):

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7264?pr=idea
It hasn't autocomplete and shortcuts are little bit difficult:) But very useful for me.